# Omission of auxiliary verbs in coordinated clauses

Tags: coordination

Can I write

> This approach has been supported by the academic community **and has been** followed by some commercial approaches

or

> This approach has been supported by the academic community **and followed** by some commercial approaches

I look for the rule for omission of some words in coordinated clauses.

Comment: Why the second passive tense includes"have been" ? ( in the first sentence, I mean)

Comment: @Cardinal just a mistake

Comment: Certainly you may.

Comment: @StoneyB you mean I both sentences are correct and can be used?

Comment: @Ahmad Yes indeed.

Comment: This same question also has answers [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/172144/omission-of-auxiliary-verb) and [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126565/can-the-auxiliary-verbs-be-optional-sometimes). It's referred to as "gapped coordination".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can always omit such things if clarity is not compromised.

Comment: You mean both sentences are equivalent and they can be used alternatively? (if clarity be kept)

Comment: Yes, absolutely